# responsive media query firing while printing multiple copies in IE 8

Tags: css, printing, responsive-design, media-queries

So while on desktop version of site in IE 8 I will hit the print button twice to print two copies of a web page. However the second copy (and every copy following) is printing as though on a responsive version. I have tried @print body 100% @screen body 100%, but nothing seems to fix it other than commenting out the @media only screen and (max-width:30em) section of my css. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support media queries (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), so you're `@media only screen and (max-width:30em)` css is probably overiding your print styles

Comment: Although saying that, it is very strange that the first copy prints properly ...

Comment: I will probably just end up doing a conditional formatting for it, just very strange to me that this wouldn't occur on the first print but all the rest